# Is there any logical reason of having different tablespace for indexes?

Tags: oracle, indexing, tablespace

Hi Can some let me know why we created different table space for Index and data.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is a widespread belief that keeping indexes and tables in separate tablespaces improves performance.  This is now considered a myth by many respectable experts (see [this Ask Tom thread - search for "myth"](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1463404632043)), but is still a common practice because old habits die hard!

#### Third party edit

Extract from asktom: ["Index Tablespace"](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11%3A0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:901906930328) from 2001 for Oracle version 8.1.6 the question

- Is it still a good idea to keep indexes in their own tablespace?
- Does this inhance  performance or is it more of a recovery issue?
- Does the answer differ from one platform to another?

First part of the Reply

```
Yes, no, maybe.

The idea, born in the 1980s when systems were tiny and user counts were in the single 
digits, was that you separated indexes from data into separate tablespaces on different 
disks.

In that fashion, you positioned the head of the disk in the index tablespace and the head 
of the disk in the data tablespace and that would be better then seeking 2 times on the 
same disk.

Drives back then were really slow at seeking and typically measured in the 10's to 100's 
of megabytes (if you were lucky)


Today, with logical volumes, raid, NN gigabyte (nn is rapidly becoming NNN gigabytes) 
drives, hundreds/thousands of concurrent users, thousands of tables, 10's of thousands of 
indexes - this sort of "optimization" is sort of impossible.

What you strive for today is to be able to manage things, to spread IO out evenly 
avoiding hot spots.

Since I believe all things should be in locally managed tablespaces with UNIFORM extent 
sizes, I would say that yes, indexes would be in a different tablespace from the data but 
only because they are a different SIZE then the data.  My table with 50 columns and an 
average row size of 4k might belong in a tablespace that has 5meg extents whereas the 
index on a single number column might belong in a tablespace with 512k or 1m extents.

I tend to keep my indexes separate from the data but for the above sizing reason.  The 
tablespaces frequently end up on the same exact mount points.  You strive for even io 
across your disks and you may end up with indexes and data on the same devices.
```

Comment: +1, and I'm looking forward to the day when this habit does finally die.

Comment: Additional Tom's thread on this topic: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1463404632043

Comment: Our database has been set up the same way by a third party with this structure 3 tablespace for our foobar-project: `foobar_index, foobar_data, foobar_LOB` and these tablespaces on top: `SYSAUX, SYSTEM, TEMP, UNDOTBS1`. Are there drawbacks regarding this number of tablespaces?

Comment: I didnt get the second las paragraph, can you help me clear it up ?

Comment: So its still good to store index in separate tableSpace due to the second last paragraph?

Comment: @AlpitAnand That's what he says

Comment: Then it must always be good at least in most cases, as index column is always tried to keep as less as possible?

Comment: @TonyAndrews please do tell if i am right on wrong in this matter? Thanks

Comment: @AlpitAnand I'm sorry I don't really know.  Those are Tom Kyte's words not mine - it wasn't even me who added them to my original answer!

Comment: @TonyAndrews Oh ok..!!! Thanks a lot, Tony for the reply, have to dig it by myself. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It makes a sense in 80s, when there were not to many users and the databases size was not too big. At that time it was usefull to store indexes and tables in the different physical volumes.

Now there are the logical volumes, raid and so on and it is not necessary to store the indexes and tables in different tablespaces.

But all tablespaces must be locally managed with uniform extends size.  From this point of view the indexes must be stored in different tablespace as the table with the 50 columns could be stored in the tablespace with 5Mb exteds size, when the tablespace for indexes will be enought 512Kb extended size.

Comment: I disagree that extent sizes must be uniform -- for almost all applications automatic segment sizing will be entirely adequate.

Answer (score 2):

- Performance. It should be analyzed from case to case. I think that keeping all together in one tablespace becomes another myth too! It should be enough spindles, enough luns and take care of queuing in the operating system. if someone thinks that making one tablespace is enough and is the same like many tablespaces without taking in consideration all other factors, means again another myth. It depends!
- High Availability. using separate tablespaces can improve high availability of the system in case that some file corruption, file system corruption, block corruption. If the problem occurs only at index tablespace there is a chance to do the recovery online and our application still being available to the customer. see also: http://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2008/05/02/indexes-in-their-own-tablespace-recoverability-advantages-get-back/
- using separate tablespaces for indexes, data, blobs, clobs, eventually some individual tables can be important for the manageability and costs. We can use our storage system to store our blobs, clobs, eventually archive  to a different layer of storage with different quality of service