# Indexes and tablespace

Tags: oracle, indexing

When we have created some indexes as part of performance tuning,

`CREATE INDEX index_emp ON emp(eid);`

The index created in a default tablespace say `myTS_D1`. When I checked, some of the indexes are having their tablespace value
`myTs_I1`. And I understood that we should specify the tablespace name at the time of creating the index.

What is the impact ? Is this creates any issue, since some of them are in one tablespace and others in a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of having separate tablespaces is that you can put them on separate physical disks.
Maybe you have a fast SSD that you want to use for some frequently accessed indexes for example. Or maybe you want to distribute disk I/O across multiple controllers to maximize throughput.

Aside from any performance or operational impact this tablespace placement has, there is no difference. For a database user (who only sees the logical schema) it looks the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using separate tablespaces for indexes and data [does not improve performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819522/is-there-any-logical-reason-of-having-different-tablespace-for-indexes), it only creates more complexity which leads to more problems later.  The more tablespaces and datafiles your DBAs have to manage the more likely something will go wrong.